# No service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryManager' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm currently doing a project on the new version of ASP.NET. I'm getting this really annoying error when I run a new empty ASP.NET project. There's nothing else in the project than the generated code... I tried changing the CLR's, but nothing helps.

I'm getting this error:

---

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> No service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryManager' has
>   been registered.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current      web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No service for
>   type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryManager' has been
>   registered.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: No service for type
>   'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryManager' has been registered.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags
>   hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception
>   appDomainCreationException) +303
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): No service for type
>   'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryManager' has been registered.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9940016 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +261
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- I'm running the 1.0.0beta5 clr x64 on windows 8.1.

Does someone know how to solve this error?

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/650 ?

Comment: Yup I have, it's not my problem :( I've the latest versions of all the packages.

Comment: Can you please share the `project.json` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I google for 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryManager' I find several issues in github mentioning that error. It sounds like it happens when you have mismatched packages, ie if you still have some beta4 packages listed in project.json